# Pass Global Variable to custom UserForm

Tags: vba, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, outlook, outlook-addin

Have the following code that ends up with a .Count variable. I would like to take that integer value and output it to a sentence in a custom UserForm. How do I do this within the Visual Studio 2012 designer. This is really stumping me. Thanks!

```
Public Shared Property mailItem As Object
Public Shared Property BodyMatchResults As MatchCollection
Public Shared Property SubjectMatchResults As MatchCollection

Public Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, _
    ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles Application.ItemSend

    Dim mailItem As Outlook.MailItem = TryCast(Item, Outlook.MailItem)

    If mailItem IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim attachments = mailItem.Attachments
        For Each attachment As Outlook.Attachment In attachments
            AttachmentQuery(attachment, mailItem, Cancel)
        Next attachment
    End If

    Dim BodyMatchResults As MatchCollection
    Dim SubjectMatchResults As MatchCollection
    Dim RegexObj As New Regex("\b(?!000)(?!666)(?!9)[0-9]{3}[ .-]?(?!00)[0-9]{2}[ .-]?(?!0000)[0-9]{4}\b")
    BodyMatchResults = RegexObj.Matches(mailItem.Body)
    SubjectMatchResults = RegexObj.Matches(mailItem.Subject)
    If BodyMatchResults.Count > 0 Or SubjectMatchResults.Count > 0 Then
        Cancel = True
        MessageBox.Show((BodyMatchResults.Count + SubjectMatchResults.Count))

        ' Access individual matches using AllMatchResults.Item[]
    Else
        Cancel = False
    End If
```

The UserForm is pretty basic with three buttons and a warning text above it. I would like to have in that text "There were either "BodyMatchResults.count" or "subjectmatchresults.count" in your email.

Answer (score 1):

Well you obviously beging with your .count variable (which for arguments sake I'll assume is of type Integer).  Hopefully you also have your Custom UserForm which we'll assume you have called UserForm.

In that UserForm add the following code:

```
Private _count As Integer

Public Sub New (ByVal count AS Integer)
  InitializeCompponent()
  _count = count
End Sub
```

You can then use the _count variable to dipaly the informationyou want displayed.

Now when you call your UserForm you can pass your .count variable to it so that it can be used there like this:

```
dim frm as New UserForm(NumberOfCountsIWantToDisplay)
```

This basic principle will work for most situations.

**Edit**

Clearly I'm not reading things properly.  Your question had specifically asked about passing a Global variable.  You should simply be able to refer to a publically defined global variable from anywhere within your application (so long as that variable has application scope).  However global variables can be more trouble that they are worth and if in reality you simply want to pass one value from form a to form b then I would use the approach that I had originally outlined having misread the subject title, for which I apologise.

Comment: This is good info and I thank you for your time. My issue is that I have already set the global variable and have an integer that I can display using a regular MsgBox format with that variable. However, when I move over to the UserForm.Designer in VS2012, I have no idea how to make a an area on that custom userform a variable since it doens't exactly show you the code for that product.

Comment: When you say that you have no way to make an area on the userform a variable what exactly are you wanting to create?  If I read your original question correctly the userform is meant to be displaying a sentence that contains amonsgst other things that global variable.  Have I understood your requirement correctly?

Comment: Correct, custom UserForm in the designer GUI. I believe I've found the way, but it passes the variable everytime to equal zero. I have a globale variable of "TotalPII as Integer" which encapsulates the ((BodyMatchResults.Count + SubjectMatchResults.Count))
Public Sub TextBox3_Display() Handles TextBox3.VisibleChanged

        Me.TextBox3.Text = (TotalPII)

    End Sub

Comment: Like i said, It displays the TotalPII variable in the text box, but its always zero.

Comment: Two things spring to mind.  Firstly try TextBox3.text = TotalPII.ToString   and see if that helps.  The second thing is that your 'Global' variable isn't actually global  (although you ought to be receiving an error if it's not).